# get Item, assoctivate array

Tags: php

With this:

```
//Example array
$arr = array(
'db' => array('host' => 'local', 'user' => 'root'));


    public function getParam($name, $default = null)
        {
            if (array_key_exists($name, $this->params)) {
                return $this->params[$name];
            }

            return $default;
        }
```

I can get the whole db array, but what if i want to reach the 'host' only with the getParam method() how do I need to extend the getParam method for this to be flexible and work in every undependant how deep the array is?

Comment: you need to write a recursive function to drill though the array

Comment: If you're using PHP 5.4, you could just use this: `$obj->getParam("db")['host'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a better solution out there but I'd probably do a recursive solution. Something like this:

```
public function getParam($name, $default = null, $arrayToCheck = false)
{
    if (!$arrayToCheck) 
        $arrayToCheck = $this->params;

    if (array_key_exists($name, $arrayToCheck)) {
        return $arrayToCheck[$name];
    }

    // if we get here, we haven't found it
    foreach($arrayToCheck as $arrayItem)
    {
        if (is_array($arrayItem))
        {
            return $this->getParam($name, $default, $arrayItem);
        }
    }


    return $default;
}
```

That will recursively hunt through your array for your key and return the first value that matches.